# Rotate boxes around circle

Tags: jquery, rotation, geometry

On my journey to learning Javascript/jQuery - Ive been trying to figure out how to do this and I think i've totally messed up the JSFiddle.

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/y7qWw/**

What i'm trying to do is rotate a div around a circle so that it is at a specified point.

1) User clicks a link with  **Movies Left  - id=goLMovies**, which moves the div to the left of the circle

[image: example1]

1) User clicks a link with  **Movies Right  - id=goRMovies**, which moves the div to the top of the circle

[image: 2]

There will be several boxes around the div with different id's. Depending on which link with which id is clicked the relative div will rotate around to the top of the circle.

It's important that the inside html elements DO NOT rotate, like the text in the circle.

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){

!jQuery.easing && (jQuery.easing = {});
!jQuery.easing.easeOutQuad && (jQuery.easing.easeOutQuad = function( p ) { return 1 - Math.pow( 1 - p, 2 ); });

var squareController = {
create: function( square ){
  var obj = {
    angle: square.data('angle'),
    element: square,
    measure: $('<div />').css('width', 360 * 8 + parseFloat(square.data('angle'))),
    update: squareController.update,
    reposition: squareController.reposition,
  };
  obj.reposition();
  return obj;
},
update: function( angle ){
  this.angle = angle;
  this.reposition();
},
reposition: function(){
  var radians = this.angle * Math.PI / 180, radius = 600 / 2;
  this.element.css({
    marginLeft: (Math.sin( radians ) * radius - 50) + 'px',
    marginTop: (Math.cos( radians ) * radius - 50) + 'px'
  });
}
};

var spin = {
squares: [],
left: function(group){
  var self = this;
  $.each(this.squares, function(i, square){
      if(square.element.data("group")==group||group==""){
        square.measure.stop(true, false).animate(
          { 'width': '-=45' },
          {
            easing: 'easeOutQuad',
            duration: 1000,
            step: function( now ){ square.update( now ); }
          }
        );
      }          
  });
},
right: function(){
  var self = this;
  $.each(this.squares, function(i, square){
    square.measure.stop(true, false).animate(
      { 'width': '+=45' },
      {
        easing: 'easeOutQuad',
        duration: 1000,
        step: function( now ){ square.update( now ); }
      }
    );
  });
},
prep: function( squares ){
  for ( var i=0, square; i<squares.length; i++ ) {
    this.squares.push(squareController.create($(squares[i])));
  }
}
};

var dataGroup;  

$('#goL').click(function(){ spin.left() });
$('#goR').click(function(){ spin.right() });

$('#goLMovies').click(function(){ 
  dataGroup = "movies";
  spin.left(dataGroup) 
});

$('#goLSomething').click(function(){ 

  dataGroup = "something";
  spin.left(dataGroup) 
});

$('#goLAnimation').click(function(){ 

  dataGroup = "animation";
  spin.left(dataGroup) 
});

spin.prep($('.square'));

});
```

Html:

```
<a id="goR" href="javascript:void(0);">Left All</a><br/>
<a id="goL" href="javascript:void(0);">Right All</a><br/><br/>

<a id="goLMovies" href="javascript:void(0);">Go Left Movies</a><br/>
<a id="goLSomething" href="javascript:void(0);">Go Left Something</a><br/>
<a id="goLAnimation" href="javascript:void(0);">Go Left Animation</a><br/>

<div class="maincircle">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="squareOne square" data-angle="180" data-group="movies">Movies</div>
        <div class="squareTwo square" data-angle="5" data-group="animation">Animation</div>
        <div class="squareThree square" data-angle="90" data-group="something">Something?</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for all the help. If someone could comment on their code also to help me develop I would be very grateful.

Comment: Your code is too much messed up for me to fix that. I will post a fiddle with one box moving along the circle. You may extrapolate that for your case.

Comment: @RaviH Thanks, I look forward to it :)

Comment: See thykka's answer below. He has done it in style. Though I got the fiddle working, I will not post it because I feel thykka's solution is elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```js
<div class="circle">
  <p>top</p>
  <p>right</p>
  <p>bottom</p>
  <p>left</p>
  <div class="box">Wheee!</div>
</div>
```

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 200px;
}
.box {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  /*  Transfom origin at the center of the circle  */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /*  The first translate centers the element,
      the second rotates it,
      the third offsets it to the circle's edge,
      the fourth rotates it back to preserve the element's orientation */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg) translateY(-200px) rotate(90deg);
  transition: transform 1s ease-out; /* this thing animates it! */
}
```

```js
$(".circle").on("click", "p",  function(e) {
  var deg = $(e.target).html()
  deg = deg === "top"    ? 0 : // corresponding angle values
        deg === "right"  ? 90 :
        deg === "bottom" ? 180 :
        deg === "left"   ? 270 : -30;
  rotateTo(deg);
});
function rotateTo(deg) {
  var bplate = [
    "translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(", -90, "deg) translateY(-200px) rotate(", 90, "deg)"
  ];
  bplate[1] = deg;
  bplate[3] = 0-deg;
  $(".circle>.box").css({
    "transform": bplate.join("")
  });
}
```

[CSSdeck example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ulfghd89)

If you wish the rotated element's orientation to remain tangent to the circle, just drop the fourth transform from css & js.

Comment: @thykka Hey, When I put this into a fiddle, it doesn't work :/ http://jsfiddle.net/h2y9s/ can you see why?

Comment: @user3596752 Maybe... I was using SASS/Compass in CSSDeck and there's still one variable left in your fiddle. That obviously won't work, so replace the `translateY(-$size/2)` with `translateY(-200px)` (half the circle's diameter). If it still doesn't work, you might want to add browser prefixes for the CSS, because in my CSSdeck I also used -prefix-free `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js`

Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/9PhFq/

Comment: @thykka that good thanks. Can you answer me one more question? I changed the size of the circle in the CSS - How do I change the Radius so the box knows where the edge is :( - see http://jsfiddle.net/WaKJ8/1/

Comment: @user3596752 If you look at the code in the CSSdeck -link in my original answer, you'll notice I'm using a `$size` variable throughout my SCSS. In addition to setting the circle div's width, height and border-radius, this variable is used in the box's transform, as the `translateY` parameter. Of course, changing the value in CSS only will not suffice, you need to change the corresponding value in javascript as well.

Comment: @thykka  Ah yes I have solved it. Would you mind If I asked you one more question. When you click any of the links they only go clockwise. How can I get the left one to rotate anticlock wise. Also, just realised I havnt accepted ur answer. Will do now.

Comment: @thykka   This is the fiddle i'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/9PhFq/1/ - in your original css deck it does go anticlockwise but not in the jsfiddle :/

Comment: @user3596752 controlling the rotation's direction is a bit of a challenge. The problem is that if you try to query the current angle with jQuery, you'll get a transformation matrix instead of the individual transforms. Working with matrixes is hard, so it's probably better to keep track of the current angle with your own js variable and add or subtract from that when rotating. Another option would be to use a plugin, such as [Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) to allow for relative rotation values.

Comment: @thykka Hey, I managed to sort that out quite easily by using a '-' before the value to make it go the other way. Since you have used this plugin and I think the code is minified, can you tell me how I would be able to set the time it takes for them to go around. I've changed the circle to a massive 2000px and it shoots really fast to each point. I would like a nice slow scroll. p.s Thank you for all your help so far. Very Very much appreciated :)